# Codeigniter form validation error - Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name

Tags: php, codeigniter

Rule in controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('text', $this->lang->line('text_input_name'), 'required|trim|callback_ValidateTooltipTags['. $this->input->post('text') .']');
```

Callback in controller:

```
public function ValidateTooltipTags($string)
{
    $this->load->model('library_model');

    if($this->library_model->ValidateTooltipTags($string))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('ValidateTooltipTags', $this->lang->line('site_message_invalid_tooltip_tags'));

        return FALSE; //or TRUE, it doesn't matter i always get validation error
    }
}
```

I always get validation error, even if i change FALSE in callback to TRUE. Do you have any ideas, what is wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried to just return TRUE or FALSE in your function without any other logic?

Comment: Yes, i got error with both.

Comment: Then you have an error in your controller, form, … but not inside of the callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I got it:

You have not to submit a value to the validation function, just call it:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('text', $this->lang->line('text_input_name'), 'required|trim|callback_ValidateTooltipTags');
```

**Update:**

You don't have to transmit the field value, but you have to write your callback function with this parameter, like you have done. Codeigniter is submitting this value for you:

```
public function ValidateTooltipTags($string)
{
    $this->load->model('library_model');

    if($this->library_model->ValidateTooltipTags($string))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('ValidateTooltipTags', $this->lang->line('site_message_invalid_tooltip_tags'));

        return FALSE; //or TRUE, it doesn't matter i always get validation error
    }
}
```

See also the documentation: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callable-use-anything-as-a-rule

Comment: This works, but i need that parameter in callback, because iam using it in more rules.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, instead of using this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('text', $this->lang->line('text_input_name'), 'required|trim|callback_ValidateTooltipTags['. $this->input->post('text') .']');
```

Use this:

```
$text = $this->input->post('text');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('text', $this->lang->line('text_input_name'), 'required|trim|callback_ValidateTooltipTags[$text]');
```

Or:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('text', $this->lang->line('text_input_name'), 'required|trim|callback_ValidateTooltipTags['. $this->input->post(\'text\') .']');
```

Thank you for your time, Joerg.